A bunch of kids in prison in the desert, 2-3 of them escape
I want to know what the title of the movie where lots of kids are in juvenile prison because of their own case. The movie was so great with the moral of loyalty of friends.
I almost forgot about the storyline but I remember some scenes in the movie such as a kid and his friend found a mountain in the middle of the desert and climb it. But the way the mountain was shaped was like a god finger. At the top of the mountain they have water and lots of onions. Rhe kid was very happy because they were very hungry and dehydrated.
Lastly, the kids were free from that prison and suddenly there was rain that never came over a decade.

Holes from 2003 about boys in a detention camp in the middle of the desert. The relevant scenes:

Eventually Stanley carries the now ill Zero up the mountain "God's Thumb", where they find a wild field of onions and a spring, helping them regain strength [...] With justice finally being served rain returns to Green Lake for the first time in over 100 years.

Here's the trailer:




sir,how to check mark/
